# How to modify libstdc++ portfile to compile fat static library?

Tags: macos, gcc, macports, libstdc++, lipo

I am using MacPorts to set up a universal build of GCC 4.7.2. One of its dependencies is a subport called `libstdcxx`, which it builds and then deletes.

I have edited the `libstdcxx` entry in the `gcc47` portfile to keep from deleting the static `libstdc++.a` library, after rebuilding.

However, the static library is a 64-bit (`x86_64`) file:

```
$ sudo port -n upgrade --force libstdcxx +universal
--->  Computing dependencies for libstdcxx
...
$ lipo -info /opt/local/lib/libstdc++.a
input file /opt/local/lib/libstdc++.a is not a fat file
Non-fat file: /opt/local/lib/libstdc++.a is architecture: x86_64
```

I would also like to add support to this file for the `i386` architecture.

What additional steps should I follow to build a fat, static `libstdc++` library? Or is this not possible with MacPorts? Is the only other option to redistribute and compile the entirety of GCC 4.7.2 twice (to get both `i386` and `x86_64` architecture support), along with the source to my application, just to link in this one static library?

**Addition - 27 Mar 2013**

Brett Hale's suggestion did not appear to work. The build process failed. Here is a snippet of the error log:

```
:notice:configure --->  Configuring libstdcxx
:debug:configure Using compiler 'Mac OS X clang'
:debug:configure Executing proc-pre-org.macports.configure-configure-0
:debug:configure Executing org.macports.configure (libstdcxx)
:debug:configure Environment: CPATH='/opt/local/include' CXXFLAGS='-pipe -O2' CPPFLAGS='-I/opt/local/include' CFLAGS='-pipe -O2' AS_FOR_TARGET='/opt/local/bin/as' LIBRARY_PATH='/opt/local/lib' MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET='10.8' CXX='g++ -arch x86_64 i386' CPP='gcc -arch x86_64 i386 -E\
' CC_PRINT_OPTIONS_FILE='/opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_tarballs_ports_lang_gcc47/libstdcxx/work/.CC_PRINT_OPTIONS' F90FLAGS='-pipe -O2' LD_FOR_TARGET='/opt/local/bin/ld' RANLIB_FOR_TARGET='/opt/local/bin/ranlib' LDFLAGS='-L\
/opt/local/lib' OBJDUMP_FOR_TARGET='/opt/local/bin/objdump' OTOOL='/opt/local/bin/otool' FCFLAGS='-pipe -O2' OBJC='/usr/bin/clang' INSTALL='/usr/bin/install -c' AR_FOR_TARGET='/opt/local/bin/ar' NM_FOR_TARGET='/opt/local/bin/nm' FFLAGS='-pipe -O2' OBJCFLAGS='-pipe -O2' CC_PRINT_OPT\
IONS='YES' STRIP_FOR_TARGET='/opt/local/bin/strip' CC='gcc -arch x86_64 i386' OTOOL64='/opt/local/bin/otool'
:debug:configure Assembled command: 'cd "/opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_tarballs_ports_lang_gcc47/libstdcxx/work/build" && ../gcc-4.7.2/configure --prefix=/opt/local --build=x86_64-apple-darwin12 --includedir=/opt/local/incl\
ude/gcc47 --infodir=/opt/local/share/info --mandir=/opt/local/share/man --datarootdir=/opt/local/share/gcc-4.7 --with-libiconv-prefix=/opt/local --with-local-prefix=/opt/local --with-system-zlib --disable-nls --program-suffix=-mp-4.7 --with-gxx-include-dir=/opt/local/include/gcc47/\
c++/ --with-gmp=/opt/local --with-mpfr=/opt/local --with-mpc=/opt/local --with-ppl=/opt/local --with-cloog=/opt/local --enable-cloog-backend=isl --disable-cloog-version-check --enable-stage1-checking --enable-lto --enable-libstdcxx-time --with-as=/opt/local/bin/as --with-ld=/opt/lo\
cal/bin/ld --with-ar=/opt/local/bin/ar --with-bugurl=https://trac.macports.org/newticket --disable-ppl-version-check --enable-languages=c++ --disable-bootstrap --with-pkgversion="MacPorts gcc47 4.7.2_2+universal"'
:debug:configure Executing command line:  cd "/opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_tarballs_ports_lang_gcc47/libstdcxx/work/build" && ../gcc-4.7.2/configure --prefix=/opt/local --build=x86_64-apple-darwin12 --includedir=/opt/local\
/include/gcc47 --infodir=/opt/local/share/info --mandir=/opt/local/share/man --datarootdir=/opt/local/share/gcc-4.7 --with-libiconv-prefix=/opt/local --with-local-prefix=/opt/local --with-system-zlib --disable-nls --program-suffix=-mp-4.7 --with-gxx-include-dir=/opt/local/include/g\
cc47/c++/ --with-gmp=/opt/local --with-mpfr=/opt/local --with-mpc=/opt/local --with-ppl=/opt/local --with-cloog=/opt/local --enable-cloog-backend=isl --disable-cloog-version-check --enable-stage1-checking --enable-lto --enable-libstdcxx-time --with-as=/opt/local/bin/as --with-ld=/o\
pt/local/bin/ld --with-ar=/opt/local/bin/ar --with-bugurl=https://trac.macports.org/newticket --disable-ppl-version-check --enable-languages=c++ --disable-bootstrap --with-pkgversion="MacPorts gcc47 4.7.2_2+universal"
:info:configure checking build system type... x86_64-apple-darwin12
:info:configure checking host system type... x86_64-apple-darwin12
:info:configure checking target system type... x86_64-apple-darwin12
:info:configure checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
:info:configure checking whether ln works... yes
:info:configure checking whether ln -s works... yes
:info:configure checking for a sed that does not truncate output... /usr/bin/sed
:info:configure checking for gawk... no
:info:configure checking for mawk... no
:info:configure checking for nawk... no
:info:configure checking for awk... awk
:info:configure checking for libitm support... yes
:info:configure checking for gcc... gcc -arch x86_64 i386
:info:configure checking for C compiler default output file name...
:info:configure configure: error: in `/opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_tarballs_ports_lang_gcc47/libstdcxx/work/build':
:info:configure configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
:info:configure See `config.log' for more details.
:info:configure Command failed:  cd "/opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_tarballs_ports_lang_gcc47/libstdcxx/work/build" && ../gcc-4.7.2/configure --prefix=/opt/local --build=x86_64-apple-darwin12 --includedir=/opt/local/include/\
gcc47 --infodir=/opt/local/share/info --mandir=/opt/local/share/man --datarootdir=/opt/local/share/gcc-4.7 --with-libiconv-prefix=/opt/local --with-local-prefix=/opt/local --with-system-zlib --disable-nls --program-suffix=-mp-4.7 --with-gxx-include-dir=/opt/local/include/gcc47/c++/\
 --with-gmp=/opt/local --with-mpfr=/opt/local --with-mpc=/opt/local --with-ppl=/opt/local --with-cloog=/opt/local --enable-cloog-backend=isl --disable-cloog-version-check --enable-stage1-checking --enable-lto --enable-libstdcxx-time --with-as=/opt/local/bin/as --with-ld=/opt/local/\
bin/ld --with-ar=/opt/local/bin/ar --with-bugurl=https://trac.macports.org/newticket --disable-ppl-version-check --enable-languages=c++ --disable-bootstrap --with-pkgversion="MacPorts gcc47 4.7.2_2+universal"
:info:configure Exit code: 77
:error:configure org.macports.configure for port libstdcxx returned: configure failure: command execution failed
:debug:configure Error code: NONE
:debug:configure Backtrace: configure failure: command execution failed
    while executing
"$procedure $targetname"
:info:configure Warning: targets not executed for libstdcxx: org.macports.activate org.macports.configure org.macports.build org.macports.destroot org.macports.install
:notice:configure Please see the log file for port libstdcxx for details:
    /opt/local/var/macports/logs/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_tarballs_ports_lang_gcc47/libstdcxx/main.log
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're building gcc with the gcc compiler, you could try to produce universal objects / libraries with the `-arch` option:

```
sudo port -n upgrade --force libstdcxx +universal \
configure.cc="gcc -arch x86_64 i386" configure.cxx="g++ -arch x86_64 i386"
```

Comment: This caused the build to fail. I've appended the relevant part of the error log to my question.